# Sphinx "searchd" can not start

Tags: linux, service, search, sphinx

Actually i am trying to start my [Kaltura](http://www.kaltura.org) service. The default "sphinx" came along together with Kaltura has crushed and then got uninstalled. Then i installed clean dedicated of "Sphinx" ([source version from here](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/)) outside of Kaltura. I setup at `/opt/sphinx/`. Then when after setup .. i run:

```
~ # sudo /opt/kaltura/bin/sphinx/searchd
```

It is showing like:

```
Sphinx 2.0.2-dev (r2823)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'test1'
WARNING: index 'test1': preload: failed to open /var/data/test1.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'test1stemmed'
WARNING: index 'test1stemmed': preload: failed to open /var/data/test1stemmed.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
WARNING: multiple addresses found for 'localhost', using the first one (ip=127.0.0.1)
precaching index 'rt'
WARNING: last message repeated 1 times
WARNING: index 'rt': preload: failed to open /var/data/rt.lock: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
precached 3 indexes in 0.000 sec
```

What are these means? I'm not really getting why.

Answer (score 10):

At first run sudo indexer --all
It will create index files
than run searchd

Comment: Love you, that helps a lot, I couldn't find answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It says that no such file or directory for:

```
/var/data/test1.sph
/var/data/test1stemmed.sph
/var/data/rt.lock
```

And I presume that was defined in `/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf`

Has something disappeared from where it used to exist? You said its a new install, perhaps the data directory was pointed to somewhere else and needs to be configured?